# Find $a$ such that $\log _{2}^{2}x-{{\log }_{\sqrt{2}}}x=a-\sqrt{a+{{\log }_{2}}x}$ has exactly $2$ solutions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

> Find $a$ so that equation $\log _{2}^{2}x-{{\log }_{\sqrt{2}}}x=a-\sqrt{a+{{\log }_{2}}x}$ has exactly $2$ solutions.

**My approach:** Since that $$\log_{2}(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)} \quad \text{and} \quad \log_{\sqrt{2}}(x)=\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\sqrt{2})}$$
then, we can re-write the equation as $$\left(\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}\right)^{2}-\left( \frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(\sqrt{2})}\right)^{2}=a-\sqrt{a+\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(2)}}$$
Let $t:=\ln(x)$ so the equation above we can re-write in terms  of $t$ as $$\left(\frac{1}{\ln(2)}t\right)^{2}-\left( \frac{1}{\ln(\sqrt{2})}t\right)^{2}=a-\sqrt{a+\frac{1}{\ln(2)}t}$$

Then, the idea that I was thinking is squaring both sides of the equation, but there appears an equation of degree 4 that is difficult to solve. How could I continue from there? or maybe a simpler approach?

---

**New approach:** Using the point out of @Ross Millikan and since that $$\log_{\sqrt{2}}(x)=\frac{\log_{2}(x)}{\log_{2}(\sqrt{2})}=2\log_{2}(x)$$
and let $t:=\log_{2}(x)$ so the equation can be we-write in terms of $t$ as $$t^{2}-2t=a-\sqrt{a+t} \implies t^{2}-2t\color{blue}{+1}=a-\sqrt{a+t}\color{blue}{+1} \implies (t-1)^{2}=a+1-\sqrt{a+t}$$
or maybe $$ t^{2}-2t=a-\sqrt{a+t} \overset{y^{2}=a+t}{\implies} (y^{2}-a)^{2}-2(y^{2}-a)=a-y^{2}$$
solving a little the expression above we can see that $$y^{4}-2y^{2}a+a^{2}-2y^{2}+2a-a+y^{2}=0$$

how can I solve this?

Comment: There is no reason to change to natural logs because everything is in base $2$.  Note that $\log_{\sqrt 2}x = 2 \log_2 x$ so you can define $y=\log_2 x$ and get rid of the logs.  The second term on the left should not be squared.  None of that gets rid of the fact that on squaring to clear the root you have a quartic.  The good news is that the left side is $y^2-2y$, so you can complete the square by adding $1$ and have $(y-1)^2$ on the left.  That might help.

Comment: Note that you accidentally squared the $\log_{\sqrt 2}x $ term

Comment: @RossMillikan I added your hint, but how can I continue from here?

Comment: Let $b = a + 1$ and $z = t - 1$ to get $z^2 = b - \sqrt{b + z}$. Still not evident, but looks cleaner.

Comment: I added my new attempts for the problem. But, I have problem with the quartic equation, I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: The idea of Saeed's answer is nice, but its conclusion is wrong. I think that the answer is $a\gt 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit***: @mathlove noticed problems with my initial solution. My effort to resolve those problems ended in a major revision of the solution. Please comment if you find mistakes in this new version.

Let's take off from where you calculated that $t^2-2t=a-\sqrt{a+t}$ . Our aim is to find a value (or values) for $a$ such that the above equation has exactly 2 real answers for $t$. Let's also keep in mind the implicit constraint that
$$a+t \ge 0 \Rightarrow t \ge -a \qquad(1)$$
This is because the given problem includes $\sqrt{a+t}$ . An important implication of (1) is that if $a$ is negative then $t$ should be positive, and if $t$ is negative then $a$ should be positive.

Another constraint that is derived from our starting equation is that
$$t^2-2t \le a \qquad (2)$$
where the equality holds when $a+t=0$. Besides, (2) means that if $a < 0$ then $t^2-2t=t(t-2) < 0$ , which implies that $0 < t < 2$.

And two other constraints, which we can derive from (2) are
$$t^2-2t+1 = (t-1)^2 \le a+1 \qquad (3)$$
$$0 \le (t-1)^2 \le a+1 \Longrightarrow a \ge -1 \qquad (4)$$

Alright, here we go:
$$t^2-2t=a-\sqrt{a+t}$$
$$t^2-t=a+t-\sqrt{a+t}$$
$$t^2-t+\frac{1}{4}=a+t-\sqrt{a+t}+\frac{1}{4}$$
$$(t-\frac{1}{2})^2 = (\sqrt{a+t}-\frac{1}{2})^2$$
$$t-\frac{1}{2} = \pm(\sqrt{a+t}-\frac{1}{2})$$
So we have two (quadratic) equations
$$t-\frac{1}{2} = +(\sqrt{a+t}-\frac{1}{2}) \Rightarrow t^2 = a+t \qquad (5)$$
and
$$t-\frac{1}{2} = -(\sqrt{a+t}-\frac{1}{2}) \Rightarrow (t-1)^2 = a+t \qquad (6)$$
Let's look more carefully at (5). The solutions to this quadratic equation are
$$t_1 = \frac{1 + \sqrt{1+4a}}{2} , t_2 = \frac{1 - \sqrt{1+4a}}{2}$$
For these solutions to exist, we should have $a \ge -\frac{1}{4}$.

Consider $t_1$. There seems to be no problem with $t_1$ for $-\frac{1}{4} \le a$ . In this range of $a$ , $t_1$ seems to satisfy constraints (1),(2),(3) and (4).

Now consider $t_2$. If $a > 0$ then by constraint (2) we should have:
$$t_2^2 - 2t_2 \le a$$
$$(\frac{1 - \sqrt{1+4a}}{2})^2 - 2(\frac{1 - \sqrt{1+4a}}{2})= \frac{-1+2a+\sqrt{1+4a}}{2} \le a$$
$$-1+2a+\sqrt{1+4a} \le 2a$$
$$\sqrt{1+4a} \le 1$$
$$1+4a \le 1$$
$$a \le 0$$
which is a contradiction with our assumption of $a > 0$. So, $t_2$ does not exist for $a > 0$. There seems to be no problem with $t_2$ for $-\frac{1}{4} \le a \le 0$ . In this range of $a$ , $t_2$ seems to satisfy constraints (1),(2),(3) and (4).

Note that if $a = -\frac{1}{4}$ then $t_1=t_2=\frac{1}{2}$.

Let's now look at (6). The solutions to this quadratic equation are
$$t_3 = \frac{3 + \sqrt{5+4a}}{2} , t_4 = \frac{3 - \sqrt{5+4a}}{2}$$
For these solutions to exist, we should have $a \ge -\frac{5}{4}$ , but we also have the stricter constraint (4), which requires that $a \ge -1$.

Consider $t_3$. If $a > 0$ then $t_3$ violates constraint (3). So, $t_3$ does not exist for $a > 0$. On the other hand, if $-1 < a \le 0$ then by constraint (1) t should be non-negative and by the implication of constraint (2) we should have $0 \le t \le 2$. But applying this range of $a$ in the calculation of $t_3$ results in $2 < t_3$, which is in contradiction with constraint (2). Finally, note that if $a=-1$ then $t_3=2$ , but this result violates constraint (3). Therefore, it seems that $t_3$ is not a solution to the equation for any value of $a$.

Now consider $t_4$. It seems that for $a \ge -1$ , $t_4$ satisfies constraints (1),(2),(3) and (4).

Note that although in the formula we get $t_3=t_4=\frac{3}{2}$ for $a=-\frac{5}{4}$ , these are not solutions of the main equation, because the value of $a=-\frac{5}{4}$ violates constraint (4).

Now let us see in what conditions $t_1$ or $t_2$ might be equal to $t_4$. From $t_1 = t_4$ it follows that $a=-\frac{1}{4}$. Also, from $t_2 = t_4$ it follows that $a=-\frac{1}{4}$. So at $a=-\frac{1}{4}$ , $t_1=t_2=t_4=\frac{1}{2}$.

Summing up our above analyses, we can see that

$t_1$ exists for  $-\frac{1}{4} \le a$

$t_2$ exists for  $-\frac{1}{4} \le a \le 0$

$t_3$ does not exist

$t_4$ exists for $-1 \le a$

Therefore, for $a > 0$ , the equation has exactly two distinct solutions ($t_1 , t_4$).

Comment: Your conclusion looks wrong. For $a=0$, the equation $t^2-2t=a-\sqrt{a+t}$ has exactly three solutions $t=0,1,\frac{3-\sqrt 5}{2}$. For $a=-1$, the equation has exactly one solution $t=1$.

Comment: Thank you for this interesting observation. Your comment is partly correct and partly wrong. For $a=0$, you are right and I am checking my solution to see where I missed the solution $t=\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}$. I will edit my answer as soon as I figure it out. For $a=-1$, the equation has exactly two solutions $t=1, 2$.

Comment: No, $t=2$ is not a solution since $2^2-2\times 2\not=-1-\sqrt{-1+2}$.

Comment: Oh my, a mistake! Thank you for noting that.

Comment: +1 I've already got the same conclusion, so it is likely that $a\gt 0$ is correct. Having $(t-\frac{1}{2})^2 = (\sqrt{a+t}-\frac{1}{2})^2$ is a very nice idea.

Comment: @Saeed Nice solution. I solved the problem and came to its conclusion and from what mathlove mentions it seems we all agree. Thanks a lot. (+1) upvote.

Comment: @АлександрПальма Thanks for the compliment. It was a pleasure solving it. And we should thank mathlove for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $$f(x)=\left(\log_2 x\right)^2-\log_{\sqrt 2} x-a+\sqrt{a+\log_2 x},$$ defined for all $x\ge 2^{-a}.$ Then we find that $$f'(x)=\frac{1}{2x\log_e 2\cdot \sqrt{a+\log_2 x}}\left(4\log_2 x\sqrt{a+\log_2 x}-4\sqrt{a+\log_2 x}+1\right).$$ Letting $M=\log_2 x,$ we see that $f'(x)=0$ whenever $16(M+a)(M-1)^2=1,$ or in other words when $$g(M)=16M^3+16(a-2)M^2+16(1-2a)M-1=0,$$ which is to say, when $\log_2 x =m,$ for some real number $m$ a root of the cubic in $M.$ This happens either once or thrice.

Now for exactly two roots of the original equation we must have a unique solution to the cubic. We find that the discriminant of $g'(M)$ is given by $$\Delta=16^2(a-2)^2-3\times 16\times 16(1-2a)=16^2(a+1)^2>0$$ for all real values of $a.$ Thus to ensure a unique solution we must have that $$g\left(\frac{a-2+|a+1|}{3}\right)g\left(\frac{a-2-|a+1|}{3}\right)>0.$$ This gives us a preliminary condition on $a.$

Now for the values of $a$ satisfying the inequality above we have ensured that $f'(x)$ vanishes exactly once, namely whenever $x=2^m,$ where $m=m(a)$ is the unique solution of $g(M)=0.$ Finally, since for $x\to +\infty,$ we have that $f(x)>0$ and for $x=2^{-a}$ we have that $f(x)=a(a+1),$ it follows that if $a=-1$ or $a=0$ we already have one root, and if these values of $a$ satisfy the previous condition then we have found two values of $a.$ On the other hand if $-1<a<0$ then there cannot be two roots if $a$ also satisfies the previous condition.

This leaves us with the case when $a<-1$ or $a>0,$ so that $f(2^{-a})>0.$ Thus in this case there are also exactly two roots provided the previous condition is satisfied and also the minimum value $f(2^m)$ is negative. This gives us a further condition on $a,$ namely that $(m-1)^2-(1+a)+\sqrt{a+m}<0.$

In summary we must have that $a$ satisfies the following conditions:

(1) $g\left(\frac{a-2+|a+1|}{3}\right)g\left(\frac{a-2-|a+1|}{3}\right)>0,$

and exactly one of the following:

(2) $a=-1$ or $a=0,$

or

(3) $a<-1$ or $a>0$ and $(m-1)^2-(1+a)+\sqrt{a+m}<0.$

Given these, then $f(x)=0$ has exactly two roots.

*PS.* Note that the conditions are to be selected as (1) and (2) **or** (1) and (3).

Comment: There is such $a$. For example, for $a=1$, the equation has exactly two solutions $x=1,2^{(1+\sqrt 5)/2}$.

Comment: You are wrong: there are exactly two solutions for any $a>0$. Derivative is $$f'(x)=\frac{-4 \log 2 \sqrt{a \log 2+\log x}+4 \log x \sqrt{a \log 2+\log x}+\log ^{\frac{3}{2}}2}{2 x \log ^22 \sqrt{a \log 2+\log x}}$$

Comment: @mathlove You're right. Thanks, I've corrected my work.

Comment: @Raffaele Yes, I miscalculated the derivative. I however disagree with you that $a$ can be arbitrary -- see my work above.

Comment: I think that you have an error in "for $x=2^{-a}$ we have that $f(x)=a(a+1),$ it follows that if $a=0$ or $a=1$ we already have one root".

Comment: @mathlove Oops, true. Adjusted.

Comment: @Allawonder Wow :-) Nice solution. Thank so much (+1) upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat oddly, this becomes easier by first eliminating $a$.  Using your substitution for $t$, let $b=\sqrt{a+t}$.  Then $a=b^2-t$ and the equation becomes
$$t^2 - 2t = b^2 - t - b$$

Or $$
0 = t^2 - b^2 - (t - b)
  = (t-b)(t+b-1)
$$
At this point it might be tempting to get back to $t$ by replacing $b$ with $\sqrt{a+t}$.  Don't do it.  When solving equations with radicals, it's almost always better to solve for the value of the radical instead of solving for the original variable.  The reason is that constraint on $b$ is just $b\ge0$, which is very convenient.  So keep solving for $b$ by getting rid of $t$ with $t = b^2-a$.

$$
\begin{cases}
(b^2 - b - a)(b^2 + b - a - 1)=0\\[2ex]
b\ge0
\end{cases}
$$

The 4 solutions for $2b$ and the requirement for $b\ge0$ are:

1. $1-\sqrt{1+4a}$,  where $-1\le4a\le0$
2. $1+\sqrt{1+4a}$,  where $-1\le4a$
3. $-1+\sqrt{5+4a}$,  where $-4\le4a$
4. $-1-\sqrt{5+4a}$, never non-negative

Whenever root 1 is valid, so are roots 2 and 3.  So, aside from degenerate roots, the only way to just have two roots is with roots 2 and 3 but not 1.  So, $a>0$

### Degenerate Roots

It is important to remember that roots can be degenerate.  While we established that for $-1\le4a\le0$, there are 3 roots, we cannot eliminate that range just yet.  What if there's some value of $a$ in that range where 2 of the 3 roots are equal.

There are two possibilities

1. $b_1 = b_2$
   Then, $4a = -1$ and the third root $b_3$ equals the other two so we will have a triple degenerate root and only 1 distinct root.
2. $b_3 = b_1$ or $b_3=b_2$

Then $-1+\sqrt{5+4a} = 1 \pm\sqrt{1+4a}$

But, since $$(\sqrt{5+4a}\pm\sqrt{1+4a})(\sqrt{5+4a}\mp\sqrt{1+4a})=4$$

If $\sqrt{5+4a}\pm\sqrt{1+4a} = 2$, then $\sqrt{5+4a}\mp\sqrt{1+4a} = 2$ from which it follows that $\sqrt{1+4a}=0$ and again we would end up with a triple degenerate root.

This leaves us with $a>0$ as the solution